# Please help! Creating new objects (from array?) after an object completes task

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am writing an iPhone application and here is the overall synopsis:
An object is on the screen and moves based on accelerometer input - I have that working - it moves to the edge of the screen and doesn't go off = perfect. Now, what I want to happen is as soon as that object hits any of the four screen edges, it should stop and stay put on the screen, and a new object should 'appear' and start moving due to the accelerometer input, so now two objects would be on the screen, but only 1 moving. Eventually there could be 20 objects built up around the edge, but only 1 object will be moving at a time.

So I have now gotten the help I needed to check for edge hits etc, but I am now trying to switch the way I was getting boxes to show up on the screen. I originally was putting images on the screen through the view controller, but now what I want to do is start with one box in the center, when it hits an edge, it should stop and stay, and a new image will appear in the center and start moving due to accel input as described above. So do I just use an array to pull the images from? Do I not even put .png's on the view controller and should I just code it? Here is some of what I have trying to do this through an array:

```
//In my .h
UIImageView *blocks;
NSString *blockTypes[3];

//In my .m
blockTypes[0] = @"greenBox1.png";
blockTypes[1] = @"greenBox2.png";
blockTypes[2] = @"greenBox3.png";
```

Thanks in advance for any help! The help so far has been great!

Answer (score 0):

You should't test if newX and newY are equal to 30 and 50. You should test if they are less than 30 and 50 respectively.

Edit:
I would do it like this:

```
loat newX = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.x + (accel.x * 12);
float newY = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.y + (accel.y * -12);
if(newX > 30 && newY > 50 && newX < 290 && newY < 430) {
    [[mutableBoxArray lastObject] setCenter: CGPointMake(newX, newY)];
} else {
    MyBox *myBox = [[MyBox alloc] init];
    [mutableBoxArray addObject: myBox];
    [myBox release];
}
```

Edit 2:
Add the following in your interface file

```
NSMutableArray *mutableBoxArray;
NSArray *imageNamesArray;
```

Then in your implementation file in the loadView add

```
mutableBoxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
imageNamesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"orangeBox1.png", 
                   @"blueBox1.png", @"greenBox1.png", @"pinkBox1.png", nil];
```

Then change the above method to

```
static NSInteger imageInt = 0;
loat newX = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.x + (accel.x * 12);
float newY = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.y + (accel.y * -12);
if(newX > 30 && newY > 50 && newX < 290 && newY < 430) {
    [[mutableBoxArray lastObject] setCenter: CGPointMake(newX, newY)];
} else {
    if (imageInt < [imageNamesArray count]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [imageNamesArray objectAtIndex: imageInt++]];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        [imageView setCenter: CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f)];
        [mutableBoxArray addObject: imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But how do I then get that object to stop and stay on the edge it hits (and not disappearing) and then create another of the same objects which takes over the accelerometer input?

Comment: Why does it disappear? How do you draw it on screen in the first place? You should continue to draw it. You can create a new object in case of the first object hitting the edge by calling a method which creates a new object. This could be done in the else statement.

Comment: No, it is currently not disappearing, but I cannot get it to stop accepting the accelerometer input and switch to a new object that needs to be created when the first one hits an edge. So right now, it hits the wall, then continues to move if you tilt phone away from wall. But I want it to hit wall, stop against wall, then create a new object that takes over the accel input.

Comment: Ok, so the mutableBoxArray array will contain each of my box color images (ex. I have orangeBox1.png, blueBox1.png, greenBox1.png, pinkBox1.png) in the array, and then the lastObject will get one at a time? It will start with one, and then when it hits an edge, a new box will appear and move around based on accel input while the other one remains locked against the edge? How do I declare the arrays and get the images added in? I truly appreciate your help, thank you for your help and thanks in advance. Coding can be so frustrating for me, but your help helps me want to conquer this! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think that should work. I am currently getting two errors though. The errors are the same and read; Request for member 'center' is something not a structure or union and they are coming at these lines...

Comment: float newX = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.x + (accel.x *                     12);
   float newY = [mutableBoxArray lastObject].center.y + (accel.y * -12);

Comment: I think that the mutableBoxArray and lastObject are different types? Could this be the problem? I'm trying to get a UIImage but the array is NS?

Comment: Ok, try this: change the line to float newX = [[mutableBoxArray lastObject] center].x + (accel.x * 12);

Comment: OK great thanks!!! So now all I have to figure out is how to set up the view controller... Do I put all of the blocks I have on top of each other in the center? Or do I just have my blank screen and each block should pop up after the previous hits the wall? Basically right now I have drawn the boxes in on the view Controller, and I'm assuming I need to delete those...